# Labeling by date in two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

```
df1
name date
A    14-04-05
A    14-05-08
A    14-08-09
A    15-01-05
B    18-07-05
B    18-08-09
B    18-10-02
C    19-01-03
C    19-02-04
C    19-03-30
D    16-04-01
D    16-08-04
```

```
df2
name startdate
A    14-07-07 
B    18-09-09
C    19-03-15
D    16-06-28
```

Record all dates in one dataset, The second dataset records the start date.

I want to label the records of df1, compared to the start date of df2, **record '0' if it is earlier than the start date and '1' if it is the day after the start date.**

result what I want

```
df1
name date     Label startdate
A    14-04-05 0     14-07-07
A    14-05-08 0     14-07-07
A    14-08-09 1     14-07-07
A    15-01-05 1     14-07-07
B    18-07-05 0     18-09-09
B    18-08-09 0     18-09-09
B    18-10-02 1     18-09-09
C    19-01-03 0     19-03-15
C    19-02-04 0     19-03-15
C    19-03-30 1     19-03-15
D    16-04-01 0     16-06-28
D    16-08-04 1     16-06-28
```

I tried to handle it using datetime, but it didn't work..

Simple example dataset sample

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', '2015-12-21'],['A', '2015-12-22'], ['A', '2015-12-25'], ['B', '2018-01-28'],['B', '2018-02-28'],['B', '2018-03-28']]),
                   columns=['name', 'date'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', '2015-12-23'], ['B', '2018-03-01']]),
                   columns=['name', 'startdate'])
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for add new column and then compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater with [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new column by position, for convert to numeric `0,1` is used [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['startdate'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left')
df.insert(2, 'Label', df['date'].gt(df['startdate']).view('i1'))
print (df)
   name       date  Label  startdate
0     A 2014-04-05      0 2014-07-07
1     A 2014-05-08      0 2014-07-07
2     A 2014-08-09      1 2014-07-07
3     A 2015-01-05      1 2014-07-07
4     B 2018-07-05      0 2018-09-09
5     B 2018-08-09      0 2018-09-09
6     B 2018-10-02      1 2018-09-09
7     C 2019-01-03      0 2019-03-15
8     C 2019-02-04      0 2019-03-15
9     C 2019-03-30      1 2019-03-15
10    D 2016-04-01      0 2016-06-28
11    D 2016-08-04      1 2016-06-28
```

Or:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['startdate'])

df1['startdate'] = df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['startdate'])
df1.insert(2, 'Label', df1['date'].gt(df1['startdate']).view('i1'))
print (df1)
   name       date  Label  startdate
0     A 2014-04-05      0 2014-07-07
1     A 2014-05-08      0 2014-07-07
2     A 2014-08-09      1 2014-07-07
3     A 2015-01-05      1 2014-07-07
4     B 2018-07-05      0 2018-09-09
5     B 2018-08-09      0 2018-09-09
6     B 2018-10-02      1 2018-09-09
7     C 2019-01-03      0 2019-03-15
8     C 2019-02-04      0 2019-03-15
9     C 2019-03-30      1 2019-03-15
10    D 2016-04-01      0 2016-06-28
11    D 2016-08-04      1 2016-06-28
```

Comment: It`s working, thank you. I have 2questions,  1. in insert, 2 means 0 or 1?  2. Where does i1 of view come from?..

Comment: @ybin - it means position, `1` means add second column. `view` is used for convert boolean to `0,1` like `True->1`, `False->0`

Comment: so, Is i1 changing the true/false value of gt to 1/0, Is it okay to think that 'i1' has a fixed meaning of changing the boolean value, not the value that is specified separately?

Comment: @ybin - I think it is smallest integer, `i`, but I cannot find it in docs.

Comment: If the dates are the same, can you specify 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @ybin - Do you think in `df1.insert(2,` ? It is only position of new column, be free change ot to `0,1,2` for see difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` it:

```
print (df1.assign(new=(df1["date"]>df1["name"].map(df2.set_index("name")["startdate"])).astype(int),
                  start=df1["name"].map(df2.set_index("name")["startdate"])))

   name      date  new     start
0     A  14-04-05    0  14-07-07
1     A  14-05-08    0  14-07-07
2     A  14-08-09    1  14-07-07
3     A  15-01-05    1  14-07-07
4     B  18-07-05    0  18-09-09
5     B  18-08-09    0  18-09-09
6     B  18-10-02    1  18-09-09
7     C  19-01-03    0  19-03-15
8     C  19-02-04    0  19-03-15
9     C  19-03-30    1  19-03-15
10    D  16-04-01    0  16-06-28
11    D  16-08-04    1  16-06-28
```